# Image doesn't appear in Safari, but shows when you point to in in the server

Tags: html, image, safari

I have a problem - I have an image in my nav bar.

http://bit.ly/a8GrvG

It doesn't show on the page, but when you go to it on the server (open image in new window), you can see that it is there. This only occurs in Safari.

That makes no sense. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What image in the nav bar? Please be specific.

Comment: Your Web server reports that `favicon.ico` (which I suppose is the file you refer to) exists but is empty. Firefox 4b on Mac OS doesn't display it either, nor do Chrome on Mac OS and Windows. It also doesn't work for IE8.

Comment: On the right hand side of the nav bar, you'll see a missing image question mark. That's the one that is missing. The image is not the browser icon, it is one of the images in the top right nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to restart Safari. Not sure why that would happen. I reloaded the page many times to empty the cache. Anyway. That's the answer in this case.

Thanks All.